# A problem with footnote - missing number, treated as zero

Tags: footnotes

Can any one help with this problem? The command

```
\footnote[$\dag$]{.....}
```

displays an error message (missing number treated as zero). However when i press r button the footnote is displayed correctly. The error is not displayed if i use a number instead of a symbol, namely, if a write

```
\footnote[1]{.....}
```

The following MWE shows the problem (i use greek)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\def\eng#1{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\sg}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\sa}{\selectlanguage{american}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
%\usepackage{pst-solides3d} % 3D drawing
%\usepackage{pgfplots}      % 3D drawing
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,named]{xcolor}
\WarningFilter*{mdframed}{You got a bad break}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
\usepackage[usetwoside]{mdframed}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\def\wlog#1{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericInfo}[2]{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{bbm}
 %\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} % IMPORTANT PACKAGE FOR THE SITUATION


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
Το πρώτο πραγματικά διεθνές πρότυπο ήταν το \textbf {μέτρο}\index{μέτρο}     (που εν συντομία γράφεται ως που καθιερώθηκε ως το πρότυπο του \textbf {μήκους} από την Γαλλική Ακαδημία Επιστημών κατά την δεκαετία του 1790. Το πρότυπο μέτρου, αρχικά ορίστηκε ως το ένα δεκάκις εκατομμυριοστό της απόστασης ανάμεσα στον ισημερινό της γης προς κάποιον από τους πόλους της\footnote[$\dag$]{$^\dag$Είναι ενδιαφέρον να επισημάνουμε, πως οι σύγχρονες μετρήσεις της περιφέρειας της γης, αποκαλύπτουν πως το σχεδιασμένο πρότυπο μήκος διαφέρει περίπου κατά το $1/50$ του $1\%$. Καθόλου άσχημα!}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the optional argument is a number, the choice of symbol is then depending on how `\thefootnote` is defined, to print the value for that number, as a footmote ymbol or number o rletter etc

Comment: the example posted shows no error and does not use `\footnote`

Comment: yes, by mistake i cut and pasted the footnote command instead of using copy and paste .. I corrected the error ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `memoir` class, which you are using, it is simple to change footnote numbering from the default Arabic numbers to other schemes. See section *12.1.2 Styling* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). To change from the numeric to a symbol scheme:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} % use symbols
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{One}

More text\footnote{Two}
\end{document}

If you wanted Roman numerals instead of Arabic then:

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
```

You don't need the `footmisc` package.

Answer (score 0):

with the definition of `\fnsymbol` you have, dagger is 2, so it seems you want

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\def\eng#1{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\sg}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\sa}{\selectlanguage{american}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
%\usepackage{pst-solides3d} % 3D drawing
%\usepackage{pgfplots}      % 3D drawing
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,named]{xcolor}
\WarningFilter*{mdframed}{You got a bad break}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
\usepackage[usetwoside]{mdframed}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\def\wlog#1{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericInfo}[2]{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{bbm}
 %\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} % IMPORTANT PACKAGE FOR THE SITUATION


\begin{document}


Το πρώτο πραγματικά διεθνές πρότυπο ήταν το \textbf {μέτρο}\index{μέτρο}     (που εν συντομία γράφεται ως που καθιερώθηκε ως το πρότυπο του \textbf {μήκους} από την Γαλλική Ακαδημία Επιστημών κατά την δεκαετία του 1790. Το πρότυπο μέτρου, αρχικά ορίστηκε ως το ένα δεκάκις εκατομμυριοστό της απόστασης ανάμεσα στον ισημερινό της γης προς κάποιον από τους πόλους τη\footnote[2]{ςΕίναι ενδιαφέρον να επισημάνουμε, πως οι σύγχρονες μετρήσεις της περιφέρειας της γης, αποκαλύπτουν πως το σχεδιασμένο πρότυπο μήκος διαφέρει περίπου κατά το $1/50$ του $1\%$. Καθόλου άσχημα!}

\end{document}
```